# How to set indexes when adding columns to a table in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, schema, laravel-8

The column I added appears after created_at and other columns.

```
public function addColumnTable($table_name,$field_name,$field_type){
        Schema::table($table_name, function (Blueprint $table) use($field_name,$field_type) {
            $table->{$field_type}($field_name);
        });
    }
```

Comment: This question is hardly a question at all, vague reference to the problem in the title and the question itself is very sparse. Please explain and elaborate on your problem, maybe with what the table is now, what you expect to add to it with what indexes :)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I had to use it:

```
public function addColumnTable($table_name,$field_name,$field_type){
    Schema::table($table_name, function (Blueprint $table) use($field_name,$field_type) {
        $table->{$field_type}($field_name)->after('id');
    });
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).